# Nodejs array still empty after pushing objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have two REST routes, one use the `CarManagerModel` to to add a car and another one to delete a car

```
class CarManagerModel {
    constructor() {
        this.carList = [];
        this.nextCarID = 1;
    }

    async addCar(carDescription) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            const car = new Car(this.carID);
            const res = car.setup(carDescription);
            this.nextCarID += 1;
            this.carList.push[car];
            resolve(res);
        });
    }

    async deleteCar(carID) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
            console.log("CAR LENGTH: ", this.carList.length)
            console.log("NEXT CAR ID: ", this.nextCarID)
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }

}
module.exports = new CarManagerModel();
```

I use the CarManagerModel in this way

```
const CarManagerModel = require('../CarManagerModel');

CarManagerModel.addCar(desc)
CarManagerModel.deleteCar(id)
```

The problem is when I try to delete a car, `this.carList` is always empty. However `this.nextCarID`  is correctly incremented.

I tried to use that, I also tried to push simple string, but the array still empty. Any idea?

```
const that = this before the 
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
this.carList.push["test"];
```

Comment: Can you turn your code into a runnable snippet (without that exports/require) which demonstrates the issue? You can use the editor's toolbar button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why are your functions async and using promises? there is nothing asynchronous happening in them? You either need to get rid of all the promises / async stuff because its not needed, or else `await` your `CarManagerModel.addCar(desc)` -

```
await CarManagerModel.addCar(desc);
await CarManagerModel.deleteCar(id);
```

Also, `this.carList.push[car]` is not valid syntax, it's `this.carList.push(car)`

I've simplified your example a little as I don't know what `Car` is, but it runs here -
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&useJavaScript=true#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgMKQE4FlIDtIHMCmaB7AE13DgG9g5q5QCNoAXZAV1EYOQAoBKCqmoMYALAJbQAdKBQAZcYzgBeOAG0AugG4Bg6iPESMuAB6MkyAJIARJXACMWwQF8QgmAE8MoOJCJEzXaWRLXGhQZFEAB0ZRej5KHRpkXEYWZAw4QwB3OAAFZAIAW3FcLndPOC4k6AJwADdcABo4JIArXHY+RQA+fgSEugYFQJtyZz6dPUlDEzMrOABqZXttcbhJqVl5CQiWaGEAlB4HVeoqmvqD5COVp2unFxoyrxJwZNx-QKs4m8Tk1PSsrl8kVoCUnhUznVGs1cG0OkoevETmtkG5esiBtVXhJwARsFwAEQIACCACU4DIAKIAOQA4gAVAASAC44ASmutAnImDjcBhsCIeD9+vQsbgcXjCdTKQANemIMlwKys9lrMRTYymFBfYU6Ry0SCMUDCCr4fJXdHI35wxhcM2cO7IsZ9RyO6jOYAezFDFDoLB4QgvGyAsx+nD4VDEUi8LTAUrQDxeXgI-iQTKQUQ+tCYcOB0gSHx+FBcADkADMCAQS0K0xms2GA5GXhIXm9-LYha7eCAQEA

Comment: This should be a comment (only), not an answer.

Comment: how so? It provides the two things potentially needed to fix the problem

Comment: @trincot Javascript 101 Hint: Functions are objects, so retrieving a missing property using brackets will simply return undefined and not break the code.

Comment: @andy, please post your code inside your question, not behind a link (you can use a Stack Snippet using the toolbar).

Answer (score 0):

Considering the code mentioned in the question, I've removed the promises and it should be written like this:

```
class CarManagerModel {
    constructor() {
        this.carList = [];
        this.nextCarID = 1;
    }

    addCar(carDescription) {
        const car = new Car(this.carID);
        const res = car.setup(carDescription);
        this.nextCarID += 1;
        this.carList.push(car); // Corrected the syntax of push
        return res;
    }

    deleteCar(carID) {
        console.log("CAR LENGTH: ", this.carList.length)
        console.log("NEXT CAR ID: ", this.nextCarID)
    }

}
module.exports = new CarManagerModel();
```

```
const CarManagerModel = require('../CarManagerModel');

CarManagerModel.addCar(desc)
CarManagerModel.deleteCar(id)
```